# Проблемы с установкой Verdaccio

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Не получается установить verdaccio,незнаю как решить проблему.[image: Ошибки:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, в пути до твоего проекта указано имя папки с непозволительным символом "пробела" )
Переименуй папку "HW JS" на "hw_js" например